# How to export list of lists to a CSV without "Row[{}]" text?

Tags: export, csv-format

[image: FindTextualAnswer]

When I export a CSV file using the code above, I get something like this:

[image: Row]

I'd like to export the answers / text on the right column without "Row[{}]" but just the raw text. Is this possible?

Code:

```
answer[question_, numberofanswers_] := 
  Export[StringJoin[question, ".csv"], 
   FindTextualAnswer[articles, question, 
    numberofanswers, {"Probability",     
      "HighlightedSentence"}]]

articles = WikipediaData /@    
  WikipediaSearch["Content" -> question];

answer["What model occurs in all the sciences?", 1000]
```

Furthermore, is it possible to export corresponding Wiki page titles and links next to these answers or no?

Comment: please post the code itself in a Markdown code block, not an image, so that people can copy it and try to modify it easily! :)

Comment: @thorimur Great point! So sorry about that! Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot try your code in version 10.1 but I suspect this is similar:

```
table = {{0.1, Row[{"first", "row"}, " "]}, {0.2, 
    Row[{"second", "row"}, " "]}, {0.3, Row[{"third", "row"}, " "]}};

ExportString[table, "CSV"]
```

> ```
> 0.1,Row[{"first", "row"}, " "]
> 0.2,Row[{"second", "row"}, " "]
> 0.3,Row[{"third", "row"}, " "]
> ```

An adjustment:

```
ExportString[table /. r_Row :> ToString[r], "CSV"]
```

> ```
> 0.1,first row
> 0.2,second row
> 0.3,third row
> ```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! For those who stumble upon this, here's what I added to get it to export a CSV file: `answer[question_, numberofanswers_] := WriteString[CreateFile[StringJoin[question, ".csv"]], ExportString[FindTextualAnswer[articles, question, numberofanswers, {"Probability", "HighlightedSentence"] /. r_Row :> ToString[r], "CSV"]]`